# How to put a different style shadow under the Header?

Tags: css, shadow

How can i put a shadow under the `header` like this one?

[image]

https://www.000webhost.com/login-cpanel

I know that i can put a `box-shadow` but i want a shadow similar to that of 000webhost.

How can i do it?

Comment: How did they do it?

Comment: @freedomn-m haha i'm thinking that it's not with `css`... i guess

Comment: https://www.000webhost.com/static/default.000webhost.com/images/shadow.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an image positioned off the bottom edge of DIV.holder

```
#header .holder:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -21px;
    content: '';
    height: 21px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://www.000webhost.com/static/default.000webhost.com/images/shadow.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

It might be possible to mimic that effect with layered `box-shadows` instead of images but it would be ugly and unwieldy code.

The only *relatively* elegant way to do it without using a separate image is to create a small SVG shadow and then embed that SVG code directly into your CSS background. Tools like https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ make this fairly easy.

Here's a quick codepen showing it in action. https://codepen.io/alexmwalker/pen/ZMVNbo

The SVG lacks some of the visual subtlety of the original PNG, but it scales better and removes the need for an extra asset from the process. Plus you can change the shadow color with a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the page you'll see the shadow belong to `:after` selector of CSS. Look on the `background` property you see it inserts image as background.

[image]

So, that shadow is created by image. No special CSS skills required in here.